# What's the differenct between passing a function and the function call itself in javascript?

Tags: javascript

In the application I'm building I'm polling for a status update and I have noticed that if the call is made as follows the timeout fires continuously:

```
setTimeout($.get("http://localhost:8080/status", function(data) { UpdateStatus(data);}), 1000);
```

While if use a function instead the timeout fires every 1000 ms:

```
 setTimeout(function() {$.get("http://localhost:8080/status", function(data) { UpdateStatus(data);})}, 1000);
```

Why?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is my function call that should be scheduled by setTimeout executed immediately?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2037203/why-is-my-function-call-that-should-be-scheduled-by-settimeout-executed-immediat)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the first example, you're *calling* `$.get` and then passing its return value into `setTimeout`. In the second example, you're not calling the function at all; you're giving `setTimeout` a function that *it* will call later, which will then call `$.get` for you.

This is easier to see with a simpler test case:

```
function test() {
    alert("Hi there!");
}

// WRONG, *calls* `test` immediately, passes its return value to `setTimeout`:
setTimeout(test(), 1000);

// Right, passes a reference to `test` to `setTimeout`
setTimeout(test, 1000);
```

Note that the first one has parentheses (`()`), the second one doesn't.

When you want to pass parameters to the function, you have to do it indirectly by defining another function:

```
function test(msg) {
    alert(msg);
}

// WRONG, *calls* `test` immediately, passes its return value to `setTimeout`:
setTimeout(test("Hi there!"), 1000);

// Right, passes a reference to a function (that will call `test` when called) to `setTimeout`
setTimeout(function() { test("Hi there!"); }, 1000);
```

Answer (score 3):

In the first example the first parameter to `setTimeout` is getting assigned the **result** of `$.get` (wrong), whereas in the second example it is actually receiving a parameter of type function, which will be correctly evaluated as a set of javascript statements every x milliseconds.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be passing the result of a function call to `setTimeout` - there's no sense in doing that.
First argument should be the function itself, not the call.

Why it fires continuously - a strange side-effect, who knows :)