# weird behavior in javascript execution timing

Tags: javascript, runtime, scope

i was a reading book named async javascript , one of the example of this book tried to show that events in javascript will trigger when processor has no instruction to do in the same process . for the proof of his word he brought an example :

```
for (var i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
  setTimeout(function(){ console.log(i); }, 0);
};
```

the output is :

```
4
4
4
4
```

everyhting is ok and i expected the result . but when i put the "console.log(i)" out of function the result will change .

```
for (var i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
  setTimeout(console.log(i), 0);
};
```

the output is :

```
1
2
3
```

i don't know why the output is different in those examples . i know its about variable scopes , but don't know exactly the reason . i hope if someone can help.

Comment: @adeneo: Are you sure this is an exact duplicate? The question is asking why the output of `console.log` is different to `setTimeout`.

Comment: @Matt - Yes, it's a duplicate, the first setTimeout function creates an async function scope, while the second setTimeout does nothing, as the function isn't referenced but called directly.

Comment: *"i don't know why the output is different in those examples"* Because you are calling `console.log(i)` **immediately** and pass the return value `undefined` to `setTimeout`. Arguments are always evaluated first, so if you have `foo(bar())`, `bar` is called first and its return value is passed to `foo`. See also http://stackoverflow.com/q/3800512/218196

Comment: @adeneo: ... and no-where in your linked duplicate is that explained. I've voted to reopen.

Comment: Made my comment an answer, but I'm sure it's a duplicate. If you find one, let me know or just close it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is my function call that should be scheduled by setTimeout executed immediately](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2037203/why-is-my-function-call-that-should-be-scheduled-by-settimeout-executed-immediat)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> i don't know why the output is different in those examples

Because in the second case you are calling `console.log(i)` **immediately** and pass the return value `undefined` to `setTimeout` (instead of passing a function like in the first case).
Arguments are always evaluated first, so if you have `foo(bar())`, `bar` is called first and its return value is passed to `foo`.

You can verify this by adding `console.log('after');` after the loop. In the first case, you should get

```
after
4
4
4
```

and in the second case, you will get

```
1
2
3
after
```

demonstrating that `setTimeout` is not adding anything to the event queue.

See also [Calling functions with setTimeout()](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3800512/218196)

> i know its about variable scopes

Actually it's not, it's all about timing, the moment when `console.log` is executed.

Comment: yes . apparently its not about scope. `Arguments are always evaluated first` is the exact answer . thanks

Answer (score 2):

When you call `setTimeout(expr,t)`, `expr` gets evaluated, hoping it returns a function. In your second case `console.log(...)` doesn't return anything, but it gets evaluated nonetheless. What you see is the side-effect of this evaluation prior to passing the result to `setTimeout`.