# Why does jQuery on/off method behave differently from external script

Tags: javascript, jquery

Clicking the header toggles between hello/goodbye when the script is embedded. Why does it only work for two clicks when the code is in an external script?

Embedded case:

```
<html>    
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
</head>    
<body>
<h1 id="title" onclick="sayGoodbye();"> Hello </h1>
<script type="text/javascript">
function sayGoodbye() {
console.log("goodbye");
$("#title").html("Goodbye");
$("#title").click(function() {
$("#title").html("Hello");
$("#title").off("click");
});
};
</body> 
</script>
```

External case:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Jquery click</title>
</head>
<body>

<h1 id="title"> Hello </h1>
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script src="click.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is click.js:

```
function sayGoodbye() {
 console.log('goodbye');
 $('#title').html('Goodbye');
 $('#title').click(function () {
  console.log('hello');
  $('#title').html('Hello');
  $('#title').off('click');
 });
}

$(function(){$('#title').on('click', sayGoodbye);});
```

Comment: try by using this
$(function(){$('#title').off('click').on('click', sayGoodbye);});

Comment: Yes that worked, but why does it need different syntax? Seems like an easy way to introduce a bug.

Comment: this is because of event handling & event delegation. Using on is event delegation.This snippet  $('#title').on('click', sayGoodbye) will initiate the handler but wont execute.Execution will take place on click.So off click will remove and handler before any click takes place

Comment: To be clear, this is not a case of event delegation.  `on` *can* do event delegation, but event delegation specifically entails listening for a bubbled event on an ancestor of several child elements which emit it (typically facilitated through the `selector` argument of `on`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your second example, `.off` is going to deregister *both* event handlers.  From [the docs](http://api.jquery.com/off/):

> If a simple event name such as "click" is provided, all events of that type (both direct and delegated) are removed from the elements in the jQuery set.

In your first example this isn't an issue since you're attaching the first handler inline yourself, not through jQuery's API.

A more concise solution to this case would be to simply hook up a single handler and maintain/toggle its state:

```
$(function () {
    var isHere = true;
    $('#title').click(function () {
        $(this).html(isHere ? 'Goodbye' : 'Hello');
        isHere = !isHere;
    });
});
```

In the event (no pun intended) you ever do need to hook up an event handler for only one invocation, don't forget that [`one`](http://api.jquery.com/one/) also exists.