# Javascript Promise.prototype.then() ordering problem

Tags: javascript

I am new to JS.
I just went to MDN website
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then
to play around the example given.
I changed the example to

```js
var promise1 = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  resolve('Success!');
});

promise1
  .then(value => console.log(value))
  .then(console.log('1'))
  .then(console.log('2'))
  .then(console.log('3'))
  .then(console.log('4'))
  .then(console.log('5'));
```

I expect the result to be Success! then 1 and all the way to 5.
However, the result is 1 to 5 and then Success!
It seems a little weird to me.
I have already chained it well but not 'branching' it. Thanks a lot

Comment: The `console.log('1')`, ... are called and the result of the `log` is passed as callback to the `then`

Comment: Not exact duplicates but the same reason [Why does click event handler fire immediately upon page load?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7102413/why-does-click-event-handler-fire-immediately-upon-page-load), [Calling functions with setTimeout()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800512/calling-functions-with-settimeout), [Why is my function call that should be scheduled by setTimeout executed immediately?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2037203)

Comment: In `foo(bar())`, `bar` is always executed **before** `foo`. The return value of `bar` is passed to `foo`.

Comment: Thanks, everyone! It took me some time to think about what you have said and then I realized it is the difference between passing func()  as an argument and just passing func. I would remind myself later should I encounter similar problems! Thanks again. It helps a lot.

Answer (score 2):

You are giving the result of the `console.log` expressions to `then`, instead of functions that will log the numbers when executed:

```js
var promise1 = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  resolve('Success!');
});

promise1
  .then(value => console.log(value))
  .then(() => console.log('1'))
  .then(() => console.log('2'))
  .then(() => console.log('3'))
  .then(() => console.log('4'))
  .then(() => console.log('5'));
```

Comment: AHHHHH!!!! Yay, that's right. I should pass a function but not the result to the .then(). Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Ari.Chau Glad to help you out!

Answer (score -4):

That is because you've used `then(console.log(...))` This will executed `console.log` and use the result as the parameter passed to `then`

It is something like this:

```js
var promise1 = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  resolve('Success!');
});

var par1 = console.log('1'),
    par2 = console.log('2'),
    par3 = console.log('3'),
    par4 = console.log('4'),
    par5 = console.log('5');

promise1
  .then(value => console.log(value))
  .then(par1)
  .then(par2)
  .then(par3)
  .then(par4)
  .then(par5);
```

Comment: The output is still the same. The other answer has it right.

Comment: @trincot I wan't trying to create the correct output. I was trying to explain why he gets this output.

Comment: I think most did not understand. Usually people give an answer with an explanation and a solution... You have given an explanation and another way to reproduce the problem. :/